# Example of a symplectic Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, symplectic-geometry

Knowing that a symplectic  Lie group is a Lie group $G$ endowed with a symplectic form $\Omega$ that is left-invariant. Take $\omega=\Omega(e)$. For every $x,y,z\in \mathfrak{g}$
$$ \omega([x,y],z)+\omega([y,z],x)+\omega([z,x],y)=0. $$
The product is defined by
$$\omega(x\cdot y,z)= -\omega(y,[x,z]) \quad \text{for all } x,y,z\in\mathfrak{g}, $$
is left-symmetric and compatible.

I would like to have a concrete example of a Lie group, with an explicit form

Comment: See the examples given [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjH-sSVoN_4AhVxVPEDHZI_CvgQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1307.1629&usg=AOvVaw0acf6ej4k5mVzP46yVB9f8), e.g., Example $4.7$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Lie group $H_3\times \Bbb R$, where $\Bbb R$ is the abelian Lie group (with coordinate $t$) and $H_3$ is the Heisenberg group consisting of all real matrices of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & z \\
0  & 1 & y \\
0 & 0  & 1  
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $H_3\times \Bbb R$ admits a left-invariant symplectic structure given by the form
$$
\omega =dx\wedge (dz-xdy)+dy\wedge dt
$$

Comment: How can I prove that this form is indeed a left-invariant symplectic form?

Comment: It is easy to verify that there is a non-degenerate $2$-cocycle $\omega$ in $Z^2(\mathfrak{g})$ in the Lie algebra, i.e., satisfying $ \omega([x,y],z)+\omega([y,z],x)+\omega([z,x],y)=0, $ and $\det(\omega)\neq 0$, where we can view $\omega$ as $4\times 4$-matrix. So the Lie algebra is symplectic and hence the form defines a left-invariant symplectic structure on the above Lie group.